# active admin - editing form for Parent with has_many Children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have `parent` has many `children` relation. I want to easily manage children of specific parent.

I am trying like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Parent" do
    f.input :name
  end

  f.inputs 'Children' do
    f.has_many :children, new_record: true do |c|
      c.input :name
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

But I am getting:

undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

I have Rails 5. Is there a better way to make this work? What is the best way to allow user to manage child objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f.has_many :children do |c|
  c.inputs "Children" do
    c.input :name 
    #repeat as necessary for all fields
  end
end
```

Make sure to have this in your parent model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
```

Comment: accepts_nested_attributes_for was a solution! Thanks a million times man! :D

Comment: and you may also need to add, in Parent model: `has_many :children, inverse_of: parent` to stop the nested form from failing to submit because of missing parent_id. Hope this helps someone.